# Acher Kain Versus Acher Kach

Tags: tefilla, chanuka, blessing

It seems there are two Versions of Al Hanissim one says Kain one says Kach which one is right and what is the underlying logic for each?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ואחר כן is the Biblical Hebrew form (e.g., Lev. 14:36), while ואחר כך is Rabbinical Hebrew (e.g., Berachos 2:2). So this is one instance of the more general debate as to whether the prayers should follow Biblical Hebrew precedents where possible, or whether this isn't important.

In this case, the older version was ואחר כך; R' Shabse Sofer, a prominent grammarian of the 17th century (whose siddur was indeed considered to be a model of proper dikduk) suggested saying ואחר כן instead, and so this became a popular variant.

Comment: Thanx for correcting my Eror and for the source again amazing Job.

Comment: Can you post more information about the Siddur? Can you post a link to it or something? A copy of the page maybe? Is there commentary on the page?

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing more of it also, Especially his version of Kaddish.

Comment: @Seth: from an article by R. Baruch Oberlander (on the Baal Hatanya's siddur and its sources) I gather that there is no extant copy known of the printed siddur, but that there is a manuscript copy which was edited and published in 5747 and 5754 (elsewhere online I see that the editors were Yitzchak Satz and David Yitzchaki). There are also later siddurim that tried to follow R. Shabse as closely as possible, including the Shaloh's Siddur Shaar Hashamayim, and R. Azriel of Vilna's Siddur Derech Siach Hasadeh (both available on Hebrewbooks).